# C converting character command line arguments to an integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C and trying to figure out arrays and command line arguments.  I have:

```
int main(int argc, int **argv) {
    int vals[8];
    for(int i = 0;i < 8;i = i + 1) {
        vals[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d", vals[i]);
    }
}
```

I call it with `./file 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and I would expect it to spit out `12345678`, but instead, it spits out `01234567` which to me says that it's just printing the array positions.  How do I get to actually print/access the value of `vals[i]`, and/or make sure that the command line value is actually being properly assigned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use any other example to test your program. Try `./file 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`.

Comment: `atoi` issues 0 for your program name because it failed to convert to integer.

Comment: Which is why, generally speaking, `atoi()` is a bad idea and you should use one of the `strto___()` functions.

Comment: @JohnHascall `/strto[a-z]+/` will also return `0` but set errno in certain implementations

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name of the program (`./file`).  `atoi()` will return `0` when given such a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `argv[1]` In order to exclude the first element of `argv` which is the program name. A simple way to do this is to increment `argv` at the top of the program.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    argv++; /* argv[0] is the program name */
    int vals[8];
    for(int i = 0;i < 8;i = i + 1) {
        vals[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d", vals[i]);
    }
}
```

On a side note, you should check the value of `argc` prior to accessing elements at index `i` in `argv`

Comment: why completely ignoring `argc` ?

Comment: See my edit, please. Furthermore, I think for his particular question, telling him about the possiblity of undefined behavior is out of scope.

Comment: It might have worked but, rather than incrementing `argv`, it would have been better to start the loop with `i = 1`.   And have the loop condition related to `argc`.   Reading from `argv[i]` if no such argument has been given yields undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

argv [0] is the name of the program.

The arguments start at 1. You should also get in the habit of using argc in loops.

```
 int main(int argc, int *argv[]) 
 {
     for(int i = 1 ; i < argc ; ++ i ) 
     {
       int val = atoi(argv[i]);
       printf("%d", val);
     }
 }
```